# create a pylon-based web site to download android app

Tags: android

For our company internal use, we would like to create create a website for downloading android apps. Anyone has some insight about this? Can a traditional file-serving server work?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When clicking on a Android Apk file on the web it will automaticlly downlaod and ask the user to install it, this will also show any permissions that are required too. So any type of file-serving server will work just fine for this.